# Sharepoint 2013 Online - Exception from HRESULT: 0x81079613

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am currently having this error when trying to create a site from a site template on sharepoint 2013 online. The error is intermittent.

Here is the log generated:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x81079613 - 
>   Server stack trace: 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SPWebCollectionProvider.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection_SubsetProxy.Add__Inner(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, SPWebTemplate_SubsetProxy WebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection_SubsetProxy.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, SPWebTemplate_SubsetProxy WebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection_SubsetProxy.Add(String strWebUrl,
>   String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID,
>   SPWebTemplate_SubsetProxy WebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions,
>   Boolean bConvertIfThere)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add__Inner(String strWebUrl,
>   String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, SPWebTemplate
>   WebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String
>   strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, SPWebTemplate
>   WebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)
>   at